# Extra field causes duplication

Tags: merge, unique

I had a unique SQL Script based on a learner's ID but when I inserted an extra field, it created extra lines per learner because the course title could be matched on more than 1 criteria based on the learner.

How can I get 1 row per learner again?

E.G, Indiana Forbes below:

```
Learner_ID  Name      Surname     Course_Title
33000515    Dary      Brahim      L3 Ext Dip in IT
33000676    Indiana   Forbes      BTEC National Foundation Diploma 
33000676    Indiana   Forbes      UAL L3 Extended Diploma
```

Is there a way to merge the BTEC course into the same cell as the UAL L3 course so that Indiana will have 1 row again?

Comment: You forgot to show the script _and_ the source data. Make an [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: The Fiddle doesn't work for me as it doesn't have permission rights to look at our server

Comment: SELECT Distinct 
STEN_Student_ID AS Learner_ID
, STUD_Forename_1 AS Name
, STUD_Surname AS Surname
, PRPI_Title AS Course_Title
, CASE WHEN STYR_In_Care = 1 THEN 'YES' END AS 'LAC_Tickbox'
, CASE WHEN GNUC_Code_6 = '1' THEN 'YES' END AS 'In_Care_Custom'

FROM dbo.STEN

INNER JOIN dbo.STUDstudent ON STEN_Student_ID = STUD_Student_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance ON  STUD_ISN = PRPI_ISN
INNER JOIN dbo.GNUCustom ON STUD_ISN = GNUC_Entity_ISN
INNER JOIN dbo.STYRstudentYR ON STEN_Student_ID = STYR_Student_ID AND STEN_Year = STYR_Year

WHERE GNUC_Code_6 = '1'

Comment: Of course it can't look at your server. That's why in the fiddle you create the needed tables _and_ populate them with data, on the left panel. The right panel then has your queries against this structure.

Comment: Apologies, very new to this but when I create a query I get the following message: SELECT command denied to user 'user_9_2454230'@'100.96.7.34' for table 'sten'

Comment: Works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81070b/1/0 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯